# Some facebook account failed to login by facebook ios sdk

Tags: facebook, authentication, facebook-ios-sdk

Our ios app uses Facebook login, and recently we found some Facebook accounts can't login. The server gives us the following response:

```
{"error":{"message":"An unexpected error has occurred. Please retry your request
           later.","type":"OAuthException","code":2}}
```

After using facebook access token debugger and input the access token we found from the gdb:

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/access_token?q=AAABZCwfIHg0IBAFLqDpQG2ZCYlxGWS0bBXvIwypOxIJ7q8VPNtcOo0eE2LiZBNT9YdWD18prYvhw78Cq7BPE4yhkxrZCBEWnxjM5ef35lwZDZD

It shows that the "User ID" is unknown.

Then we try another Facebook account which can login successful, and it shows in access token debugger the right "User ID".

Because only some account has problem, we think its a account related problem. We have searched it and changes some setting of the account, but nothing helps.